# Is it possible to collect external libraries used when developing applications under a folder?

Tags: c#

We use external libraries when developing projects in C#. These libraries are located in the main directory when the application is compiled. In order to create a more organized folder structure, can we collect these libraries under a folder called "Application\Plugins" when the application is installed on computers? In summary, what I want to do is to keep the libraries I use in a folder, not in the main directory.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual goal? When the application is installed the user should have a shortcut to use, he/she should never need to even see the folder structure or any .dll files at all. Also, "Plugins" would typically be used for optional, dynamically loaded plugin libraries that provide some type of extra feature. Not for required dependencies that are needed to make the program work at all.

Comment: "Plugins" generally means something different, but a "Libraries", "Dependencies", or similar folder isn't out of the question.

Comment: Look towards Nuget,npm, or any other repository for storing packages. In this model, there is a repository that provides feeds of package versions, and the client has a provider that handles requests for working with these packages. The packages themselves are downloaded to a separate folder near the project or to a cache on the user’s computer. Accordingly, you can centrally store your libraries, and a certain provider will synchronize files and service application requests to load libraries into memory. If there is a provider, how exactly to organize local storage is an implementation detail